# Need query to delete duplicate entry with certain condition

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, database-administration

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  institutionid int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  domain_update tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  delete_data tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  date datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  processed tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I have many records in **test** table with the same value.But I need single copy and need to delete duplicate entries.The condition is **institutionid**,
**domain_update** & **delete_data** should be same and **processed**=0.If these 4 column value match then it should keep 1 records and delete duplicate record.

**Sample data**

| id | institutionid | domain_update | delete_data | date | processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 0 | 2021-03-12 | 0 |
| 2 | 523 | 0 | 0 | 2021-03-22 | 0 |
| 3 | 897 | 0 | 0 | 2021-04-25 | 0 |
| 4 | 645 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-11 | 0 |
| 5 | 158 | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-23 | 0 |
| 6 | 123 | 1 | 0 | 2021-06-03 | 0 |
| 7 | 345 | 0 | 0 | 2021-06-18 | 0 |
| 8 | 897 | 1 | 0 | 2021-06-28 | 0 |
| 9 | 123 | 1 | 1 | 2021-07-26 | 0 |

**Sample output**

| id | institutionid | domain_update | delete_data | date | processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1 | 0 | 2021-03-12 | 0 |
| 2 | 523 | 0 | 0 | 2021-03-22 | 0 |
| 3 | 897 | 0 | 0 | 2021-04-25 | 0 |
| 4 | 645 | 1 | 0 | 2021-05-11 | 0 |
| 5 | 158 | 0 | 0 | 2021-05-23 | 0 |
| 7 | 345 | 0 | 0 | 2021-06-18 | 0 |
| 8 | 897 | 1 | 0 | 2021-06-28 | 0 |
| 9 | 123 | 1 | 1 | 2021-07-26 | 0 |

Here it will delete only one record with id value **6** because it has **institutionid**,**domain_update**,**delete_data** and **processed**=0 same as id value **1** but it will not delete id value **9** because **delete_data** value is different as well as it will not delete id value **8** because its **domain_update** is different.So I need query to delete duplicate entry with the condition **institutionid**,
**domain_update** & **delete_data** should be same and **processed**=0.Need help on this.

Comment: What is your MySql version

Comment: Hi @Moolya only processed = 0 used for calculation

Answer (score 2):

Use a self join:

```
DELETE t1
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN test t2
ON (t2.institutionid, t2.domain_update, t2.delete_data, t2.processed) = 
   (t1.institutionid, t1.domain_update, t1.delete_data, t1.processed)
   AND
   t1.id > t2.id
WHERE t1.processed = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6873b4b171b85573c5bdb12a974679dd).

Comment: Is it possible to update processed value to -4 for the duplicate records instead of delete?

Comment: @Moolya Of course it is possible, but the comments section is not for asking questions. Post a new question where you explain what you want with sample data and expected results.